# Auth->user() don't work in API controller in Laravel

Tags: laravel, api, authentication

In my **api.php** file, I have apiResource
`Route::apiResource('temperature', App\Http\Controllers\Api\TemperatureController::class);`

In **TemperatureController** in **store** method, I try create new Temperature:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

public function store(CreateTemperatureRequest $request){
    Temperature::create([
        'temperature' => $request->get('temperature'),
        'userName' => Auth()->user()->name,
        'created_at' => Carbon::now()
     ]);
     return true;
}
```

After the form submits, I have an error - **Trying to get property 'name' of non-object**. My form is **vueJs** component.
If I add *auth middleware* in the controller:

```
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth:api')->only('store');
    }
```

and call `Auth('api')->user()->name`,
I have error **401 (Unauthorized)**.

I **am not using Passport for authentication**. I use **standard Laravel authentication**, but the form is a Vue component and I use an API controller.

How can I get user data in the API controller?

Comment: I think you're using Passport for authentication. If you don't need OAuth, I suggest you switch to Sanctum. I had the same issue with Passport, but don't remember how to solve it, because I've been using Sanctum for a long time.

Comment: I don't using Passport for authentication. I use standart Laravel authentication, but form is vue component and I use api conroller.

Comment: API auth requires a token so make sure you're sending the correct one from vue

Comment: You need SPA authentication, look at https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sanctum

Comment: Use either the function helper (lowercase)`auth()->user()` or the facade (uppercase A) `Auth::user()` Also, does Vue has the `api_token` set ?

Comment: It might be that `auth:api` is using  `api` guards while normal laravel authentication uses `web` guard. That might be the reason for this.

Answer (score 1):

use auth() instead

```
auth($guard)->user()->name
```

$guard may be

'api' or 'web'

Comment: Not working. Error - Trying to get property 'name' of non-object

Comment: @SergeyS. which guard did you pass web or API?

Comment: I think, Route::apiResource use API guard, but I need standart Auth() and web guard.

Comment: @SergeyS. Just check on your user table if you had name column!! 

Pass 'api' and then dump user results

dd(auth('api')->user());

Check to see if you will get user collection

Comment: $model->user_id = auth()->user()->id ?? null;

I using this in boot for creating and work fine for me  try it @SergeyS.

Comment: In my case $guard was 'sanctum', so, to get user I used this code: $authUser = auth('sanctum')->user();

Answer (score -2):

try

```
request()->user();
```

when working with API, You must send a header with you, this is working fine with sanctum. if it doesnt work switch to [laravel Sanctum](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sanctum)